# Parse exception - s3 path not found

Tags: apache-spark

The s3 path does exist so the exception is wrong, but something about this string and the `part-*` is not working

```
.snappy.parquet")output_fix/20190115/individual/part-*
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: s3://media/data/v1/output_fix/20190115/individual/part-00000-b8450da0-15e9-482e-b588-08d6baa0637a-c000.snappy.parquet;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$DataSource$$checkAndGlobPathIfNecessary(DataSource.scala:715)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$15.apply(DataSource.scala:389)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$15.apply(DataSource.scala:389)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
```

The source for above

```
val srcDf = sqlContext.read.parquet("s3://media/data/v1/output_fix/"""+dt+"""/individual/part-*.snappy.parquet")
```

I've tried a dozen variants, including hard coding the date string. Always seeing some path issue which is bogus as the s3 path exists onmy fs

Any clues appreciated

Comment: Maybe you should just read `s3://media/data/v1/output_fix/20190115/individual` It will take all the part files inside automatically.

Comment: Have tried that variation also 20190115/individual

Comment: also tried 20190115/individual/ and 20190115/individual/*  all give me either path not found or equiv exception